# Composing Big Query in App Script

Tags: sql, google-apps-script, google-bigquery, sqldatetime

I want to compose bigquery in app script with date1 & date2 variable (as mentioned below). What is the format to pass these 2 variable?

```
var date1="20180601"
var date2="20180606"

var sql = "select * from table_query([project-name:dataset],
'table_id <= "date2" and table_id >= "date1"');";
```

Comment: I am new to apps scripting..any help regarding this is very much appreciated..

Comment: I could do with following way:  var sql = "select * from table_query([project-name:dataset],
'table_id <= \""+date2+"\" and table_id >= \""+date1+"\"');";

Comment: Can you post as an answer your own solution so other people can get help from it, please?

Answer (score 0):

I could do it in the following way:

```
var date1="20180601"
var date2="20180606"
var sql = "select * from table_query([project-name:dataset], 'table_id <= \""+date2+"\" and table_id >= \""+date1+"\"');";
```